# Returning Php multidimensional array in WordPress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have the following array stored in the wordpress options table and I need to get the value of each title

```
a:1:{s:14:"swd_line_items";a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:9:"asdfasdfa";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:13:"asdf asdf ada";}i:2;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:29:"fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff";}}}
```

I've tried nested foreach loops but nothing I do seems to work. There must be a simple solution?

```
function swd_get_line_items() {

$line_items = get_option('line_items_array');

$items = array();
foreach( $line_items as $item => $value ) {

    foreach ($value as $new => $v) {

        $items[] = array(
            $new => $v
        );
    }

}

return $line_items;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
$array = unserialize('a:1:{s:14:"swd_line_items";a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:9:"asdfasdfa";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:13:"asdf asdf ada";}i:2;a:1:{s:5:"title";s:29:"fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff";}}}');

foreach($array['swd_line_items'] as $item) {
   echo $item['title'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you mean this ?

```
function swd_get_line_items($serialized_array) 
{
    $line_items = unserialize($serialized_array);

    $items = array();

    foreach ($line_items['swd_line_items'] as $key => $item) 
    {
        $items[$key] = $item['title'];
    }

    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`get_option()` perfectly unsezrializes an array so there is no need to do it as the two other answers suggested it.
Then what you have is a two dimensional array but you are perfectly browsing it with two nested `foreach`.
By the way here is the final output of your code:
As you can see you perfectly extracted the titles:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => asdfasdfa
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => asdf asdf ada
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => fffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
                )

        )

)
```

But the issue here is that you do not return this array but you return this one:

```
return $line_items;
```

**Change it into**

```
return $items;
```